# Write the date in BDS function automatically

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I'm working with data from Bloomberg. My code is :

```
Sub Code_Fin()
Sheets("SPX").Cells(2, 3).Formula = "=BDS(""SPX Index"", ""INDX_MEMBERS"", 
""END_DATE_OVERRIDE=20210810"",""cols=1;rows=1000"")"
End Sub
```

Do you know please, how replace the ""END_DATE_OVERRIDE=20210810"" by something like ""END_DATE_OVERRIDE=today()"" ? I would like to change the date automatically.

Thank you !

Comment: Assign date to a variable, and then use it within your formula https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/date-variable/

Comment: @Hooded0ne thank you for the link. I can't find the function for datepart, when I run the code I obtain 10/08/2021 00:00. I would like to have only  10/08/2021.

Comment: @Marie Try `Format` function, your example would be `Format(Date,"yyyymmdd")`. Concatenate that to formula